# mapping current_user.name as "me" in the options for a select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

How do you include the current_user in the options for select, but map their name to "me"?

A user can assign tasks other users via a select dropdown, but if no other user is selected the task should then be assigned to that user.  I'm currently constructing this with a normal select tag with my own helper for the options:

```
 def user_select account
    account.users.reject{|u| u == current_user }.map {|user| [user.name, user.id]}    
 end
```

and in the form

```
      = f.select :user_id, user_select(@account), { :include_blank => 'me' }
```

I check to see if the :user_id param is present and set it to the current_user if not.  I know, gross, and this is becoming a smell.

So, I'd like to include the current_user in the user_select, but map their user.name as "me."  Any ideas?

(I've looked into options_for_select and collections_for_select, and while both allow you to pass in a default, you can't actually set the value.  Or, you can default it to selecting the current_user, but the way I'm doing it currently will use their actual name instead of "me").

Edit:
As per fl00r's suggestion, I've changed the user_select to:

```
  def user_select account
    me = ["me", current_user.id]    
    account.users.reject{|u| u == current_user }.map {|user| [user.name, user.id]}.insert(0, me)
  end
```

manually creating the "me" and inserting first works for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include "me" only if `current_user` belongs to account?

```
def user_select(account)
  me = ["me", current_user.id]
  account.users.reject{|u| u == current_user }.map{|user| [user.name, user.id]}.insert(0, me)
end

= f.select :user_id, user_select(@account)
```

Comment: "me" (aka the current_user) will always belong to the account.  I just want his user.name replaced with "me" in the select options.

Comment: I think setting the 'me' variable, then inserting it at 0 will work though... don't know if there's a more elegant solution though

Comment: I've edited my post to include my final code.  While I feel that it could be refactored a bit, it works, specs pass, and I'm happy.  Thank you fl00r.